# How to block this kind of URLs in robot.txt file?

Tags: php, url, robots.txt

here are two set of conditions and I want to block all url with `/search/jobdescription?` and `search/jobdescription/`

1. `http://<--sitename-->/search/jobdescription?id=0154613&css=a&act=a`
2. `http://<--sitename-->/search/jobdescription/id/0154613/css/a/act/a`

How to block both occurances in robot.txt file.

Comment: You may wish to revisit your old questions and accept answered where applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search/jobdescription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [X-Robots-Tag HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=fr-FR) to prevent indexing.